# Custom Segmented Control with round Background

Tags: swift, customization, uisegmentedcontrol

hope someone can help me....
I've created a UISegmented Control and started to change it to my application design - see screenshot below.

If you guys can see the background of the segmented option, you will see my problem. I managed to change colours, texts and some other small things with the following functions:

[What I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psZrc.png)

```
extension UISegmentedControl {

func defaultConfiguration(font: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Regular", size: 13)!, textColor: UIColor = UIColor.white, backgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear) {
    let defaultAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
        NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.font.rawValue): font,
        NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue): textColor,
        NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor.rawValue): backgroundColor
    ]
    setTitleTextAttributes(defaultAttributes, for: .normal)
}

func selectedConfiguration(font: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Regular", size: 13)!, textColor: UIColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 52, green: 0, blue: 177), backgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.white) {
    let selectedAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
        NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.font.rawValue): font,
        NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue): textColor,
        NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor.rawValue): backgroundColor
    ]
    setTitleTextAttributes(selectedAttributes, for: .selected)
    }
}
```

I wanted the background to be bigger and rounded... any ideas what I am missing? When the user clicks, it should see the following

[WHAT I NEED:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiTnL.png)

Comment: try this. https://github.com/tapptitude/TTSegmentedControl

Comment: I see, but there is a way not using this to create?

Comment: have you tried this. http://smnh.me/customizing-appearance-of-uisegmentedcontrol/

Comment: Thanks... seems more like it... Will ready and try to build with Swift